# How to scale a box based on the font size of another piece of text?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, fontsize

I'm trying to make a chapter style in a `memoir` document.

This is the current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\lefthang[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1\hspace{\marginparsep}}}

% 'mychapter' chapter-style
\makechapterstyle{mychapter}{%
  % Minimize vertical spaces
  \setlength\afterchapskip{50pt}
  \renewcommand\chapterheadstart\relax
  \renewcommand\afterchapternum{}

  % We don't print "Chapter"
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}

  % Fonts and size
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Huge\scshape}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\chaptitlefont}

  % Chapter number hanging into the paragraph
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{%
    \lefthang{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
  }

  % Small-caps title (always lowercase)
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeTextLowercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\raggedright\chaptitlefont}
}

\chapterstyle{mychapter}


\begin{document}

\chapter{This is quite a long chapter title indeed}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The result is the following:
[image: result]

Now, I would like to obtain the following:

- The spacing between the two lines should be smaller, so that the height of two lines is in total not much more than twice the height of a single line.
- The number should be high as two lines (also if the title is a single line) with the baseline aligned to the baseline of the second line (or the only line if the title is a single line).

Note that I'm using Libertine with old-style figures and the title text is lowercased, which is intentional so that the "1" is as high as a single line of text. Other numbers, like "6", would rise or descend and be larger than two lines, but this is ok. I just want the "small" numbers (like "1", which does not rise nor descend) to be as high as a double line.

This is a mockup of what I'm trying to obtain:

[image]

The main problem is that the number should be bigger regardless of whether the title text occupies two lines or not, so I cannot simply measure the box.

How may I achieve such effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters to play with include the `28pt` and `40pt` in the `\lefthang` definition, as well as the `\fontsize{28pt}{28pt}\selectfont` with which I replaced the `\Huge` in the OP's original definition

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\lefthang[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\smash{\raisebox{-28pt}{\scaleto{$#1$}{40pt}}}%
  \hspace{\marginparsep}}}

% 'mychapter' chapter-style
\makechapterstyle{mychapter}{%
  % Minimize vertical spaces
  \setlength\afterchapskip{50pt}
  \renewcommand\chapterheadstart\relax
  \renewcommand\afterchapternum{}

  % We don't print "Chapter"
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}

  % Fonts and size
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\fontsize{28pt}{28pt}\selectfont\scshape}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\chaptitlefont}

  % Chapter number hanging into the paragraph
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{%
    \lefthang{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
  }

  % Small-caps title (always lowercase)
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeTextLowercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\raggedright\chaptitlefont}
}

\chapterstyle{mychapter}


\begin{document}

\chapter{This is quite a long chapter title indeed}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In response to the OP's follow-up, here is a different, though not wholly satisfactory, approach.  One can align the baseline of the `\lefthang` with the last line of the chapter title.  This will give the OP what he/she desires if the chapter title is 1 or 2 lines in length, but will keep lowering the lefthanging chapter number if the title is 3 or more lines in length.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scalerel,tabto}
\newcommand\lefthang[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\smash{\scaleto{$#1$}{40pt}}%
  \hspace{\marginparsep}}}

% 'mychapter' chapter-style
\makechapterstyle{mychapter}{%
  % Minimize vertical spaces
  \setlength\afterchapskip{50pt}
  \renewcommand\chapterheadstart\relax
  \renewcommand\afterchapternum{}

  % We don't print "Chapter"
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}

  % Fonts and size
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\fontsize{28pt}{28pt}\selectfont\scshape}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\chaptitlefont}

  % Chapter number hanging into the paragraph
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}

  % Small-caps title (always lowercase)
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeTextLowercase{##1}%
    \tabto*{0pt}\lefthang{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\raggedright\chaptitlefont}
}

\chapterstyle{mychapter}


\begin{document}

\chapter{This is quite a long chapter title indeed}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{This is a short chapter title}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Chapter 1 heading shows as in the prior example, but chapter 2 shows as below:

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there a way to compute the parameters to make it more resilient to changes in font family and font size?

Comment: There's a problem: in case of a title of only one line, the number is positioned too low. The two baselines should be aligned. How to fix that?

Comment: @gigabytes That will be more challenging... But what if the title is 3 lines?

Comment: The number should be always as high as two lines regardless, aligned on the baseline. Yes I know it's more difficult, unfortunately...

Comment: @gigabytes The problem is that `\lefthang` which sets the chapter number knows nothing about the contents or length of the chapter title..

Comment: @gigabytes A second, though not wholly satisfactory, approach is offered in follow-up.  Any more will require pre-setting the chapter title in a temporary box and measuring its height/depth, and branching based on the result.

Comment: @gigabytes I have made another change to accommodate arbitrary chapter line length, but it requires the user to add one or two `\relax` macros to the beginning of the chapter title if the lines are 2 or more lines, respectively.

Comment: I'm doing this thing in a class, so I cannot put the burden on authors. The previous solution was good enough, is there a way to retrieve it again?

Comment: @gigabytes I have "rolled back" the answer to the prior edit.